# Update Target Unreachable, returned null

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

'm experiencing problems while trying to use the object currentCenter and display its attributes on a dialog using Primefaces but it keeps showing this error

**Error**

```
AVERTISSEMENT: /pages/centres.xhtml @151,196 value="#
 {centreMB.currentCentre.matricule}": Target Unreachable, 'currentCentre' returned null
 javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/centres.xhtml @151,196 value="#
{centreMB.currentCentre.matricule}": Target Unreachable, 'currentCentre' returned null
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findImplicitConverter(InputRenderer.java:170)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findConverter(InputRenderer.java:190)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:196)
```

**CentreManagedBean.java**

```
 public void onSelectCentreForUpdate(Centre centre) {
    try {
        setCurrentCentre(centre);
        setIdcentreselected(centre.getIdcentre());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

/**
 * Modifier Médecin
 *
 * @return vide
 */
public void updateCentre() {
    try {
        Centre c=getCentreService().getCentreById(getIdcentreselected());
        c.setMatricule(currentCentre.getMatricule());
        c.setAdresse(currentCentre.getAdresse());
        c.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
        getCentreService().updateCentre(c);

    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

**centre.xhtml**

```
   <p:column style="width:0.5%"> 
                               <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" actionListener="#{centreMB.onSelectCentreForUpdate(centre)}" update=":editCentre:updatePanel" oncomplete="updateCentre.show()"/>

                            </p:column>
```

```
            <!-- Modification -->
            <p:dialog header="Modification du centre" widgetVar="updateCentre" resizable="false" id="editP" modal="true"> 
                <p:messages id="msgs"/>  
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="updatePanel">

                <h:outputLabel for="matricule" value="Matricule: *" />
                <p:inputText id="matricule" value="#{centreMB.currentCentre.matricule}" required="true" label="Matricule" style="width: 205px" requiredMessage="Matricule: Champ obligatoire"/>                  
                <h:outputLabel for="nom" value="Nom: *" />  
                <p:inputText id="nom" value="#{centreMB.currentCentre.nom}" required="true" label="Firstname" style="width: 205px" requiredMessage="Nom: Champ obligatoire"/>
                <h:outputLabel for="prenom" value="Adresse: " />  
                <p:inputTextarea id="prenom" value="#{centreMB.currentCentre.adresse}" label="Surname" required="false" style="width: 205px" />

                </h:panelGrid>  
                <p:separator/>             
                <p:commandButton styleClass="ui-panel-titlebar-icon ui-corner-all ui-state-default" id="enregsitrer" value="Enregistrer" update="msgs" actionListener="#{centreMB.updateCentre}" ajax="true" style="width: 248px;" oncomplete="handleDialogSubmitUpdate(xhr, status, args)"/>  
                <p:commandButton type="button" styleClass="ui-panel-titlebar-icon ui-corner-all ui-state-default" value="Annuler" ajax="true" onclick="updateCentre.hide()"/>

            </p:dialog>

        </h:form>
```

thanks for your helps Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the error occurs empty therefore.
organized as follows:

```
private CurrentCentre currentCentre= new CurrentCentre();
```

or

```
public CurrentCentre getCurrentCentre(){
   if(currentCentre == null)
      currentCentre = new CurrentCentre();
   return currentCentre;
}
```

Comment: I have resolved it 
it was a problem of @SessionScoped